# Microsoft Excel file versions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, microsoft-word-2003, versioning

We have a user here who uses Word 2003 and Excel 2003 as his primary tools. He needs to keep different versions of his files over the time so he can rollback to a previous version at any time. Currently, every time he feels like a new version is needed, he uses "Save as..." and creates a copy of the document. He wants to get rid of all these files and wants to keep a single file, but he wants access to the history of his documents.

The initial request was to install a version control system (like SVN) on the user's machine and create a reposity for him on our server, but that involves coaching and supporting him if problems arise. We would like him to be as autonomous as possible without too much intervention on our side.

Then I read about Word having a version manager built-in, which allows to save multiple versions of the same document, and go back to any version at any time you wish. Eureka! The problem was solved, but then I opened up Excel to check if the same functionality exists and I was very disappointed when I clicked the File menu and did not find the Versions element.

I wanted to know if there is such a feature in Excel 2003 ? Or maybe in a newer version ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature that is built in.

You might as well teach him to use save-as (<kbd>F12</kbd>) as opposed to save.

Comment: this is already what the user is doing. He wanted another solution to manage versions rather than having to keep multiple copies of the same documents